# Making a copy of a global state to a component local state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a copy of a global state to a component local state.
I'm using Redux with hooks.

Here's my code but the local state is returning an empty a object.

```
  const transaction = useSelector((state) => state.data.transaction)
  const [localTransaction, setLocalTransaction] = useState(transaction)
```

here is the console log of my global state(transaction)
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of `useState` is set on mount, so if there is nothing in the store at that time it will be invalid and any changes made to it will also not be reflected. If you have a valid reason for storing it again in local state, then you need to do something like this instead:

```
const transaction = useSelector((state) => state.data.transaction)
const [localTransaction, setLocalTransaction] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  if (!localTransaction && transaction) {
    setLocalTransaction(transaction);
  }
}, [transaction, localTransaction])
```